# Array of pointers to objects won't fill to its allocated capacity

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, pointers

So basically I have an array of `Card` objects initialized like so...

```
Card *pile[MAX];
```

where `MAX` is 52.  This array is a member of a class called `CardPile`

The problem I'm having occurs when I try to fill an instance of `CardPile`called `drawPile` to its 52-element capacity by using a for-loop...
This is how I chose to do that:

```
char faces[] = "A23456789TJQK";
char suits[] = "SHDC";
int k = 0;
for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        drawPile.add(new Card(faces[i], suits[j]));
        //the line below is displayed on the console for debugging purposes
        cout << drawPile.pile[k]->face << drawPile.pile[k]->suit <<  ", pile size=" << drawPile.size << endl;
        k++;
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the `.add(Card*)` method...

```
void CardPile::add(Card *c){
    for(int i=0; i<52;i++){
        if(pile[i]){
            continue;
        } else {
            this->pile[i]=c;
            size++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

...and when I run the program, I get this displayed in the console...

```
AS, pile size=1
AH, pile size=2
AD, pile size=3
AC, pile size=4
2S, pile size=5
2H, pile size=6
2D, pile size=7
2C, pile size=8
3S, pile size=9
3H, pile size=10
3D, pile size=11
3C, pile size=12
4S, pile size=13
4H, pile size=14
4D, pile size=15
4C, pile size=16
5S, pile size=17
5H, pile size=18
5D, pile size=19
5C, pile size=20
6S, pile size=21
6H, pile size=22
6D, pile size=23
6C, pile size=24
7S, pile size=25
7H, pile size=26
7D, pile size=27
7C, pile size=28
8S, pile size=29
8H, pile size=30
8D, pile size=31
8C, pile size=32
9S, pile size=33
9H, pile size=34
9D, pile size=35
9C, pile size=36
TS, pile size=37
TH, pile size=38
TD, pile size=39
```

After that last line of output, the program stops running... My question is, why does the program stop after the 39th call to `add()` instead of finishing and filling the array to its allocated capacity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you initialize all `pile` element to 0? Also why don't use vector?

Comment: Ahh, that worked! I don't know why I didn't try that much earlier haha. Thank you very much! If only you didn't leave that answer as a comment so I could up-vote the hell out of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize piles element, it default has random value:

```
Card *pile[52] = {};
```

Also you could try to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of array with raw pointer

```
std::vector<Card> cards;
```

Comment: Thanks again!
And I WOULD use a vector, but my software design professor strictly prohibited us from using it (and I completed the entire assignment WITH vectors before finding this out >:( )